# Time complexity of tree algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, trees, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm new to recurrence relations and master theorem so trying to learn. Say there's an algorithm $A$ whose input is the root of a binary tree $T$. $A$ recurses so that it's called on each and every node in $T$ exactly once. The time complexity of $A$ called on a node $X$ is $O(number\:of\:nodes\:in\:subtree\: rooted\:at\:X)$.

What's the overall big O time complexity of $A$ (probably in terms of $N$, the total number of nodes in $T$)?

My (informal) approach is to imagine $T$ as a maximally imbalanced tree (single line of nodes straight down). Then the time complexities of the nodes starting from root is $N$, $N-1$, .... $1$, of which there are $N$. That becomes $(N+1)*(N/2) == N^2/2+N/2 == O(N^2)$.

However I'm not sure this holds for other types of binary trees (such as perfect). I'm struggling to come up with a formal approach.

I'm trying to use [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) and believe the recurrence relation is $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + f(n)$.

$c_{crit} = log_2 2 = 1$.

Worst case of $f(n)$ is at root of $T$ which is $O(n)$, so $f(n) = O(n^c)$ gives $c = 1$, and thus it cannot be Case 1 or 3 because $c == c_{crit}$. So it must be Case 2. But how do I determine the value of $k$ in $f(n) = \theta(n^{c_{crit}}log^{k}n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the complexity of the algorithm depends on the tree $T$. For the maximally imbalanced tree, as you computed the complexity is $O(n^2)$. Another important observation is that the complexity on this particular type of tree is $\Omega(n^2)$.

If you take a perfectly balanced complete tree, then then the root node has cost $n$; nodes at level $1$ have costs at most $n/2$; and so on...
If you sum up the costs, you get $n + 2 \cdot n/2 + 4 \cdot n/4  + \dots + n \cdot 1 = O(n \log n)$. Moreover, the complexity over this particular type of tree is $\Omega(n \log n)$.

Now, let us talk about any general tree. Any node of the tree has cost at most $n$. Suppose we assume this worst cost for every node in the tree, then the complexity is at most $n^2 = O(n^2)$. Simple!
This complexity is tight for general tree, since you already showed a worst case example of a maximally unbalanced tree to be $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Questions:

1. "complexity on this particular type of tree is $\Omega(n^2)$" -> Why Omega? Does this mean $O(n^2)$ is incorrect here (but you still wrote that the complexity is $O(n^2)$ before and at the end of your answer)?

2. Your process makes sense to me (except for the above question). However I associate formal proofs with the master theorem. Is using the theorem doable with this algorithm, and if so how?

Comment: @onepiece Both $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^2)$ are correct for the maximally unbalanced trees. Note that you computed the complexity as $(N+1)N/2$, which is both $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^2)$.

The above proof is also formal. I personally never use master theorem. Firstly, it has many cases. Secondly, I have never required it; a simple tree/substitution based schemes have always worked for me.

Comment: "Both $(^2)$ and $\Omega(^2)$ are correct for the maximally unbalanced trees" -> is this because complexity for those trees is always $n^2$? Then is $\Theta(n^2)$ also correct? Similarly, all three big notations of $nlogn$ are correct for perfectly balanced complete trees. Is this why we usually care about the big O (because if a given algorithm could have complexity 1, $n$, or $n^2$ depending on input, saying it's $\Omega(1)$ is correct but much less meaningful than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @onepiece Yes. Yes, $\Theta(n)$ is also correct. Yes all three notations are correct for balanced trees as well. 

Yes, we usually care about big O notation; however saying that complexity is $O(n^3)$ or $O(n^4)$ is also correct for you problem. But is not tight. Therefore, $\Omega()$ gives a lower bound as well. In short, $O$ + $\Omega$ together are more meaningful;

Comment: Thank you, very clear and helpful!